# String has length as member function.while array has length as final field

Tags: java, arrays, string, declaration

This is regarding java programming.Why Java developer has made length() as member function for String Object while for array reference variable they made it as final field?...
If that is not really confusing then My next question is as in any function, references are local variable stored on Stack.Then how we are able to refer field on array reference..
Please correct me if I went somewhere wrong..

Answer (score 0):

The `length` of an array isn't even a field (it can't be because arrays aren't real objects). It's a "pseudo-property" like the `class` in `Object.class`. It's a syntactic element recognised by the compiler and translated into some primitive operation.

Comment: Which Object.class are you talking?..I mean i was unable to find any property you mentioned

Comment: I didn't find anything like property for an array or for any other class in API.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: @Level29Access: That's exactly what I'm saying. There is no array class because an array is not a normal object. And that's why `length` is not a normal field (in what class would it be defined?). The compiler translates an expression like `a.length` into the JVM instruction `arraylength`, not a field access.

Comment: Similarly, `Object.class` is translated into a reference to an instance of type `java.lang.Class<Object>` describing the class `Object`.

Answer (score -1):

If you see the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.0count) of string,That scenario comes when you pass a chararray to the String `constructor.`

```
  public More ...String(char value[]) {
193         int size = value.length;
194         this.offset = 0;
195         this.count = size;
196         this.value = Arrays.copyOf(value, size);
197     }
```

And making  count  as a `final` Prevented to intialize the `count` outside of the constructor.

Comment: @SURESH ATTA ,+1 for explanation I got it length() is returning count..

Answer (score -2):

"Why" questions are always the hardest to answer. Historical reasons mostly arising from special treatment of arrays. I think properties should be restricted to simple get and set, only if there are no side effects, otherwise use functions.

Comment: See below code:

    int []a;
    a=new int[4];
    a.length=8;//Compile Time Error The Final field array.length cannot be assigned.

Comment: @Level29Access You "set" the size by initializing it whith "4". Of course you cannot change a final var.

Comment: @Fildor That what exactly I mean to say it is final..So,Why developer didn't made it method like in String class.